# How do I run executable scripts in Nautilus rather than open them in Gedit text editor?

Tags: files, gedit, execute-command

When I double-click on a script in Nautilus in order to run it, the script opens in my text editor with no option to do so.

Using Nautilus, how do I run executable text files and/or scripts?