# Zend Studio-5_5_0 not open in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

i installed Zend Studio-5.5.0 in ubuntu 13.04. but when i try to open it from bin folder it is not open. every time it open as a text editor.

Comment: When you say "it opens as a text editor" do you mean that a new text editor window opens and tries to display the contents of the executable or that the program executes and displays an empty text editor window? Can you add a screenshot please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make it executable. This is just a simple permission flag. Either:

- `chmod +x filename`
- Right click it, Properties, Permission tab, check the executable box.

Comment: it is already checked @Oli

Comment: @magExp Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/274442/why-does-ubuntu-open-executable-files-in-gedit help?